# How to skip page when scrolling in viewPager2 in android?

Tags: android

I have a viewPager2 with multiple elements inside, like a,b,c,d,e.
When I'm scrolling it currently scrolls, like we used to know a viewPager2 is scrolling.
From a to b, from b to c, and also backwards.

But how can I let him skip an element?
Desired state: When I am scrolling to left from position A it should land at C and NOT B. How can I redirect him to a position I want.

[example viewPager2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OYdK.png)

following my example, the divider elements should be skipped when scrolling.

Comment: You can set current item manually from code level.
                binding.vpLessonContent.currentItem = binding.vpLessonContent.currentItem+1

Comment: yes that is actually working. I'm getting the originally selected position from "override fun onPageSelected(position: Int)" then I can modify it and call viewPager.setCurrentItem(targetPosition). its actually working visually, but I don't know if he now trying to jump twice (first position then target position), but because its so fast, i just can't see it?

is there no other way I can hook myself into, without calling setCurrentItem manually? what I am asking myself is, at which point on codelevel the command is executed that the scrolling will hold at a certain point/position.